# Predict values based on vegetation layer

Tags: python, r, arcgis

I have point data from deer surveys and would like to predict values for areas not surveyed based on vegetation type (Grass, Disturbed, Oak, Pine, Mixed etc.)

So far I have dissolved my vegetation layer to combine adjacent polygons and used Spatial <strike>intersect</strike> Join to combine this layer with my point data. I'm now trying to predict values for polygons with Null values for the pop field (deer seen) and pop_avg field (pop/3 survey nights) based on vegetation type (text field). I'm not really sure what my next step should be if anyone has any suggestions.

EDIT: Would I need to do the prediction analysis in a program such as R or python to later bring back to map in ArcGIS?

Comment: This is probably too broad for StackOverflow. You may get more answers from [GIS.SE](gis.stackexchange.com), which is more open to questions about methodology.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out about the `randomForest` package and how it might be helpful to answer my question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176195/predict-estimate-point-values-for-unsurveyed-areas-based-on-vegetation-type

From there I was finally able to come to a solution to my problem which I answered here:  [Predict/estimate values using randomForest in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864182/predict-estimate-values-using-randomforest-in-r)