# Predict/estimate values using randomForest in R

Tags: r, data-modeling, random-forest, prediction

I want to predict values for my `Pop_avg` field in my unsurveyed areas based on surveyed areas. I am using randomForest based on a suggestion to my earlier question.

My surveyed areas:

```
> surveyed <- read.csv("summer_surveyed.csv", header = T)
> surveyed_1 <- surveyed[, -c(1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,15)]
> head(surveyed_1, n=1)
  VEGETATION                                        Pop_avg    Acres_1
1 Acer rubrum-Vaccinium corymbosum-Amelanchier spp.       0   27.68884
```

My unsurveyed areas:

```
> unsurveyed <- read.csv("summer_unsurveyed.csv", header = T)
> unsurveyed_1 <- unsurveyed[, -c(2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,15)]
> head(unsurveyed_1, n=1)
OBJECTID                                       VEGETATION  Pop_avg   Acres_1
      13 Acer rubrum-Vaccinium corymbosum-Amelanchier spp.       0  4.787381
```

I then removed rows from `unsurveyed_1` that contained vegetation types not found in `surveyed_1` and dropped the unused feature levels.

```
> setdiff(unsurveyed_1$VEGETATION, surveyed_1$VEGETATION) 

> unsurveyed_1 <- unsurveyed_1[!unsurveyed_1$VEGETATION == "Typha (angustifolia, latifolia) - (Schoenoplectus spp.) Eastern Herbaceous Vegetation", ]
> unsurveyed_1 <- unsurveyed_1[!unsurveyed_1$VEGETATION == "Acer rubrum- Nyssa sylvatica saturated forest alliance",]
> unsurveyed_1 <- unsurveyed_1[!unsurveyed_1$VEGETATION == "Prunus serotina",]

> unsurveyed_drop <- droplevels(unsurveyed_1)
```

Next I ran randomForest and predict and added the output to `unsurveyed_drop`:

```
> surveyed_pred <- randomForest(Pop_avg ~ 
+ VEGETATION+Acres_1,
+ data = surveyed_1,
+ importance = TRUE)

> summer_results <- predict(surveyed_pred, unsurveyed_drop,type="response",
+ norm.votes=TRUE, predict.all=F, proximity=FALSE, nodes=FALSE)

> summer_all <- cbind(unsurveyed_drop, summer_results)
> head(summer_all, n=1)
OBJECTID                                        VEGETATION Pop_avg   Acres_1 summer_results
      13 Acer rubrum-Vaccinium corymbosum-Amelanchier spp.       0  4.787381       0.120077
```

I would like to estimate values for the column `Pop_avg` in `summer_all`. I am assuming that I need to use the proportions generated in `summer_results`, but I'm unsure how I would do this. Thanks for any help or further suggestions.

**More information:** 
I am looking to get predicted count data for `Pop_avg` based on `Vegetation` and `Acres_1`. I am not sure if/how to use the probabalities in my output `summer_results` to achieve this or if I need to alter my model or try a different method.

**E2**
The reason I didn't think the output was right is because `Pop_avg` ranges anywhere from .333 and up (where there were deer seen) which is `Population` divided by 3. And `Population` ranges from 1 and up (i.e. 10, 20...). When I ran the model trying to predict either one I get similar numbers that range from .9xx to 2 or 3.xxx especially when I ran it with `Population`. Which didn't seem right.

**DATA:**
[summer_surveyed_sample](http://www.filedropper.com/summersurveyedsample)

[summer_unsurveyed_sample](http://www.filedropper.com/summerunsurveyedsample)

Comment: What did you try, and why does it make you think you are doing something wrong?

Comment: @AndyClifton I'm still new to R and this is the first time I have used randomForest. But from what I have seen the output in `summer_results` is a probability for the prediction. I may be wrong though. And I was trying to figure out my next steps for getting estimated values for `Pop_avg`.

Comment: Unfortunately the way you're question is written it's hard to understand; you've got a mixture of statistics and programming  You might want to focus on one or other issue and tidy up the question. Also, some example data would help.

Comment: Random forest will return values that are in the exact same units as the training data. So if your 'pop_avg' data are numbers (not proportions) there's no correction to make. If the area of your prediction site is different than your training site you would have to weight the data accordingly.

Comment: @AndyClifton I added links for my sample data along with a brief explanation why I didn't think my output looked right. I also tried running with just Vegetation as my prediction parameter with similar results.

Comment: @AndyClifton You were right about the output. The results I was getting had to do with how I was setting up my training model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem lied within my training model. I figured out that I needed to use a subset of my surveyed data where `Population` > 0 to get more accurate predictions.

```
> surveyed_1 <- surveyed_1[c(surveyed_1$Population > 0),]
> surveyed_drop <- droplevels(surveyed_1)
> surveyed_pred <- randomForest(Population ~ 
                VEGETATION+Acres_1,
                data = surveyed_drop,
                importance = TRUE)
```

Comment: So your problem was not the programming, but more to do with the model development. That's not unusual!